# How to redirect all URLs with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

How do I configure the `app.yaml` file to redirect all URLs to another URL? For example I want `http://example.appspot.com/hello` or `http://example.appspot.com/hello28928723` to redirect to `http://example.com`.

I am only serving static files at the moment. Here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
application: testapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can redirect all requests easily with a python handler. Something like

```
class FormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    if processFormData(self.request):
      self.redirect("http://example.com")
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete - that code snippet is insufficient on its own to redirect reqeusts.  Also, what about get requests?

Comment: @BrianLeathem Just posted a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18297787/282729).

Answer (score 40):

**Webapp2 has a built-in redirect handler**

No need to roll your own handler; webapp2 already comes with one.

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/hello', webapp2.RedirectHandler, defaults={'_uri':'http://example.com'}),
    webapp2.Route('/hello28928723', webapp2.RedirectHandler, defaults={'_uri':'http://example.com'}),
], debug=False)
```

The _uri argument is what the RedirectHandler class uses to define the destination. It took a lot of Google Fu to find the documentation on this but it works flawlessly in my app.

I assumed you're aware of this but you need to change your catch-all route from:

```
- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

To (python27 version):

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

Or: (pre python27 version)

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

`main.py` is the file containing the request handler + routes.

*Note: There is no static-only way to handle redirects on GAE because of the nature of static files. Basically, there's no way to do a redirect in `app.yaml` alone.*

Comment: This handles get/post/etc... It's basically the 'proper' way to do a 301 (permanent) redirect in GAE.

Comment: It's important to note that apparently App Engine doesn't support redirecting to static files/directories. I couldn't get the redirect to work. I kept getting these errors in my logs: "File referenced by handler not found: main.app". Finally, I found this, which confirmed that static files are not accessible to handlers:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734040/google-app-engine-static-pages-python-2-5-directories-etc.

Comment: @StephenKaiser Technically, it's not a redirect but you could define a new route in app.yaml that points from the old URI to the new one. Due to the architecture and the way static files are handled there's no way to define an actual 301/302 redirect on static files.

Comment: I think hello28928723 was just an example, he wanted to redirect all requests.

Comment: @Jonny There's a significant difference between how static and non-static files are handled on GAE. You could add a non-static handle in the list above the static handler specifically to catch just redirects. Either way, it's important to understand how and why static files are handled different in GAE. App.yaml is basically an instruction set for a reverse proxy where all static files are actually stored on a static file cache separately from the non-static files. 302/301 redirects aren't possible until you hit the a http server (ie not the static cache).

Comment: I tried your first example `RedirectHandler` and got `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2_extras/routes.py", line 157, in __init__
    setattr(route, self._attr, prefix + getattr(route, self._attr))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects`

Answer (score 9):

All you need (replace `app-id`, `http://example.com`):

- `app.yaml`:

  ```
  application: app-id
  version: 1
  runtime: python27
  api_version: 1
  threadsafe: false

  handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: main.py
  ```
- `main.py`:

  ```py
  from google.appengine.ext import webapp
  from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

  class AllHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
          self.redirect("http://example.com", True)

  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', AllHandler)])

  def main():
      run_wsgi_app(application)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

Comment: suggest adding "secure: optional" to the app.yaml handler so that https works also.

Comment: "secure: optional" is the default when not provided (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a **static-files-only** way to do "redirects" then do this:

In the `app.yaml`, put this as the catch-all, at the end of the file:

```
-   url: /.*
    static_files: root/redirect.html
    upload: root/redirect.html
```

Then in the `root/redirect.html` file, put this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/" />
        <script>
            location.replace("/");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

This example will redirect all unknown URLs to the root (i.e., / ). If you want another URL, just substitute `http://example.com` in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a python script that will do the redirect:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, path):
    self.redirect("http://example.com", permanent=True)
  def head(self, path):
    self.redirect("http://example.com", permanent=True)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
            [
                (r'^(.*)', MainPage)
            ])

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Note the webapp2 answer provided by @Evan Plaice works, but I was stuck with the older datastore and couldn't use python 2.7.

Comment: +1 for posting a solution that's backward compatible with webapp.

Answer (score -1):

Riffing off Evan's answer, to redirect all requests you could use regexes to do something like:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
     RedirectRoute('/<:.*>', redirect_to='/')
    ], debug=False)
```

For official docs check out:

https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html

[https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route.**init**](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route.__init__)

Comment: FYI, the "official docs" links don't work anymore.  :-/  I found this link that seems to cover it though: https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html

Answer (score -1):

The redirect handler for webapp2 (webapp2.RedirectHandler) mentioned in a previous answer will not work for post requests, as it does not contain a post method (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2.py), so you will need to roll your own python handler if concerned with posts. Something like the following:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):


    def post(self):
        self.redirect('http://example.com')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/.*', MainPage)
], debug=False)
```