# Google App Engine static pages Python 2.5 directories etc

Tags: python, google-app-engine, static, yaml, directory

I am new at this and am planning to move  my stuff from a paid web service to GAE (nothing dynamic just static pages). Believe me I have spent countless hours trying to make this work but am at an impasse whereby I achieve one result at the exclusion of another and visa versa.

I am sure it is a simple answer and that I am violating some basic principles. What I want is that the app engine page (mygaeid.appspot.com) delivers a static landing page such that other pages are available with the addition of a suffix e.g. mygaeid.appspot.com/oranges.html mygaeid.appspot.com/grapes.html  etc.

I am unable to achieve this such that I either am able to get the other pages when I add the suffix e.g. mygaeid.appspot.com/apples.html; mygaeid.appspot.com/oranges.html but not the landing page  OR with a slightly different yaml the landing page (mygaeid.appspot.com) works but there is no access to the other pages (mygaeid.appspot.com/oranges.html etc) that have a suffix.

The py file (abcdefg.py) is below and is common to the two different yamls that follow:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'htmdir/apples.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))


def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

---

Using the following yaml the landing page (mygaeid.appspot.com) works perfectly (delivering the content of apples.html), but I cannot access the page if I add a suffix e.g. mygaeid.appspot.com/apples.html or mygaeid.appspot.com/static/htmdir/apples.html etc, as soon as I add the suffix it does not work.  In the directory (htmdir) I have placed apples.html along with other html pages e.g. oranges.html etc and I cannot access any of them with this yaml.

```
application: mygaeid
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(html))
  static_files: static/htmdir/\1
  upload: static/htmdir/(.*\.(html))

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: abcdefg.py
```

If I modify the yaml as follows then the landing page (mygaeid.appspot.com) does not work but when I add the suffixes then it works perfectly e.g. mygaeid.appspot.com/apples.html; mygaeid.appspot.com/oranges.html etc deliver the appropriate pages:

```
- url: /(.*\.(html))
  static_files: htmdir/\1
  upload: htmdir/(.*\.(html))
```

Finally if I dispense with the directories altogether and using the same abcdefg.py (without the directory) the following very simple yaml actually delivers the results I want but is very unruly as all the files are stuffed in the root directory.

```
application: mygaeid
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(png|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(png|js|css))

- url: .*
  script: abcedfg.py
```

any help would be much appreciated on figuring this out.
thanks

---

thanks wooble and thanks dave I went back yet again and carefully read the logs   Wooble's solution works but I needed to put the htmdir (that contains the html) inside a directory called static.  GAE is a great (and free) solution for  static websites

your help and feedback is very much appreciated

```
SiteDirectory
-mygaeid
  -static
    -htmdir
  -js
  -css
  -images
 app.yaml
 index.yaml
(py file was removed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare files as static in app.yaml, they are not available to your application's handlers.

However, if they're really static, using the django template engine to "render" them is kind of silly; just add mappings in app.yaml to display the static files, including one to display apples.html for /:

```
application: mygaeid
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: static/htmdir/\1
  upload: static/htmdir/.*\.html

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /
  static_files: static/htmdir/apples.html
  upload: static/htmdir/apples\.html
```

(no python files needed)

Comment: @Octavio: I edited my answer to include the CSS/JS/image handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Woobie has the right answer. Let me phrase it differently.

When you put .html in `static_files`, they're served by separate services that are dedicated to serving static content. Your app will not be able to see those files. The app can only see files that are resources.

Django templates must be resources, not static files. Otherwise, the application can't see them, and the `template.render(path, ...` will fail.

A next step to getting your problem solved is (if you haven't done so aleady) is to update your post to show your current `app.yaml`, and also to show us what's being reported up in the application's logs.

Answer (score 0):

**There are technical reasons why it works this way**

The app.yaml config functions in a very simple top->bottom procedural manner.

**Matching happens in the following order:**

```
1. - url: /(.*\.(html))
  static_files: static/htmdir/\1
  upload: static/htmdir/(.*\.(html))

2. - url: /css
  static_dir: css

3. - url: /js
  static_dir: js

4. - url: /images
  static_dir: images

5. - url: .*
  script: abcdefg.py
```

To put it simply, if the file has a .html suffix it gets matched in step 1 and reroutes that request from mygaeid.appspot.com/*.html to mygaeid.appspot.com/htmdir/*.html. The *.html handler in step 5 never gets hit because all *.html routes are already spoken for.

In addition -- as the answers have already covered -- directories marked as static will not be available locally to your app handlers. I'll try to address the technical reasons why.

app.yaml acts as a configuration file for GAE's reverse proxy. Static files only change when they're uploaded so they're ideal for caching. By immediately pushing the static files to a cache server when they're deployed, GAE increases loading performance and removes unnecessary load from the app servers.

There's a good reason that static requests are counted separately and cost less than regular app requests. Every time you request a static file you're essentially pulling fetching the file from GAE's CDN. If you were to only fetch static files, then your server would have no reason to spool up in the first place.

The obvious downside to that approach is that those files don't physically exist on the same server as your app so you can't fetch or upload them directly in your app.

*Note: Also following what other answers have covered. Don't mark your template folder as static. When your app goes to load the template -- instead of grabbing it from an adjacent directory -- it'll have to send out a web request and fetch the file from a remote location. Obviously, fetching a remote file instead of a local file is going to increase load time and latency.*