# how to redirect 301 using web.xml for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-301, redirect, webdeploy

I have to redirect my default app engine page **myAppID.appspot.com** to **www.myDomain.com**.

I have created HTML files for site, created the gwt project in eclipse and deployed that project on google app engine. I have search on the net for 301 redirection, so find that as i am using java so i need a java handler to put in web.xml file or app-engine-web.xml file. I am not a developer just a web designer only know the HTML and CSS as scripting language.

So please if anybody can help me.

Comment: Is this about redirecting or do you need to map soulnyoga.appspot.com to the www.soulandyoga.com domain?

Comment: @Johnldol, sorry to say i dont know the difference between maping and redirecting. I just want that whenever user go to soulnyoga.appspot.com the url will be changed to www.soulandyoga.com i think this is redirecting or URL what is mapping?

Answer (score 0):

For redirect, you can follow the steps in this post on creating [python handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058119/how-to-redirect-all-urls-with-google-app-engine) and for mapping , follow this google document on [deploying application on google apps url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains)