# Vue production URL redirection returning 404 on gae

Tags: google-app-engine, vuejs2

I have a vue application that I want to deploy to google app engine. I have deployed it and everything works as it should but when I manually enter in a url the app responds with a 404. Is there any way I can setup the app.yaml to allow for the redirection to the SPA from a url?

```
 # GAE yml setup
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

# URL handlers
handlers:
 - url: /
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html

  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*)

  - url: .*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html

# GAE has a limit of 10,000 files so ignore node_modules and anything else thats not neccassary
skip_files:
  - node_modules/
  - .gitignore
  - src/
  - public/
  - babel.config.js
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
```

How can I redirect with handlers to a specific page on the SPA?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058119/how-to-redirect-all-urls-with-google-app-engine/18297787#18297787) about what you are trying to achieve.

This specific solution (redirect all URLs to a single URL) works in two steps, modifying your `app.yaml` and adding some source in the `.py` file.

In the `app.yaml`, by adding the [handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element): *"App Engine can handle URLs by executing application code, or by serving static files uploaded with the code, such as images, CSS, or JavaScript."*

`handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py`

And in the `.py` file, by adding the 'rule' to redirect.

`class AllHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect("http://example.com", True)
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', AllHandler)])`