# Redirecting domain to another domains specific url using google cloud app engine

Tags: java, spring, .htaccess, google-app-engine

I am trying to redirect other domain to my domain by setting up the my domains nameserver to another domain.
Ex.
My Domain: example.com
Created Nameserver: ns1.example.com

Other domain:  domain.com
Set Nameserver : ns1.example.com

When i open domain.com so it has to redirect on *example.com/redirected/domain.com*

I don't know How to do it on Google App Engine.
How can i achieve that using Spring boot application on Google App engine or is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have both domains in App Engine, you can route from one service to another using [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml). In the documentation there is an example, as it is stated there:

> The following is a sample dispatch file that routes requests to
>   `http://simple-sample.appspot.com` and requests like
>   `http://simple-sample.appspot.com/favicon.ico` to the default service.
>   All static content is served from the default service. Mobile requests
>   like `http://simple-sample.appspot.com/mobile/` are routed to a mobile
>   frontend, and worker requests like
>   `http://simple-sample.appspot.com/work/` are routed to a static backend.

And here's the configuration:

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    service: default

  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "simple-sample.appspot.com/"
    service: default

  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
  - url: "*/mobile/*"
    service: mobile-frontend

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/work/*"
    service: static-backend
```

There are more possible configurations and description of the syntax in the documentation. Also it is important not to forget to deploy with:

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```

Comment: Okay but will it work on domains. Because there is a list of domain. There domains want redirected to mydomains specific url

Comment: This configuration redirects the traffic to an App Engine service. If you want to redirect it to a domain specifically, it has to be done in the code. I found this other stackoverflow thread that explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058119/how-to-redirect-all-urls-with-google-app-engine/9428268