# Can't get a very simple app.yaml setup working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I am using Google Cloud to set up a simple site but having a lot of issues with the app.yaml file.

All I need for now is:
- Have the site always serve HTTPS
- Have all non-www redirect to www
- Have index.html be served at the root

I had a configuration that previously worked, then i tried tweaking it, but when i went to reset it... it no longer works.  Only the homepage works and every link/url returns the homepage.  This is the setup i had:

```
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /$
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: how this isn't working? what error are you getting? where are you trying to dpeloy this, App Engine? if so please share with us the logs of running `gcloud app deploy --log-http --verbosity=debug` so we can see the actual error, also providing us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help to solve this much faster

Comment: The current error I am getting is that the whole site is working on the www and non-www versions e.g.

https://www.example.co.uk  - 200 OK
https://example.co.uk - 200 OK

www versions e.g.

https://www.example.co.uk/link1  - 200 OK
https://example.co.uk/link1 - 200 OK

The logs are very long (hundreds of lines).   Is there a particularly bit that needs sharing? 

There has been no error returned when i run gcloud app deploy. (I'm deploying it using Google Cloud SDK Shell) 
It's the actual online experience that is not what I was looking for.  

Thank you!

Comment: This answer seems to be for redirecting from your appspot.com domain to your personal domain.  I have managed to get that bit working, my issue is I now have two versions of the site live on the personal domain, the www and the non-www version

Answer (score 0):

For mapping your domains, you can add and point your custom domains through the Custom Domains page by following the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains?hl=en#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app).

To redirect your requests, you can use wildcard mappings with services in App Engine by using the dispatch.yaml file. You can find instructions on how to do that [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml). If you would like to know more about routing requests, you can take a look at this documentation as well which also highlights [creating a dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-routed?hl=en).

Also you can see [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058119/how-to-redirect-all-urls-with-google-app-engine) answers.

Normally [200 OK](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#handling_errors) means that there is no error.